# how to upper case every other word in string in python

Tags: python

I am wondering how to uppercase every other word in a string. For example, i want to change "Here is my dog" to "Here IS my DOG"
Can anyone help me get it started? All i can find is how to capitalize the first letter in each word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the most compact function but this would do the trick.

```
string = "Here is my dog"

def alternateUppercase(s):
    i = 0
    a = s.split(' ')
    l = []
    for w in a:
        if i:
            l.append(w.upper())
        else:
            l.append(w)
        i = int(not i)
    return " ".join(l)

print alternateUppercase(string)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but can you help me explain the for loop? I am still new to this.

Comment: @Neal Wang **a** is a list of all of the words and **for w in a:** means for every word in the list of words. The for loop executes the underlying code for every word(**w**) in the wordlist(**a**). A good example of the for loop can be found [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm).

Answer (score 7):

```
' '.join( w.upper() if i%2 else w
          for (i, w) in enumerate(sentence.split(' ')) )
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the method you are looking for is [`upper()`](http://docs.python.org/release/2.3/lib/module-string.html).
You can use [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to split your string into words and the call `upper()` on every other word and then join the strings back together, using [`join()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)

Answer (score 1):

```
words = sentence.split(' ')
sentence = ' '.join(sum(zip(words[::2], map(str.upper, words[1::2])), ()))
```

Comment: This won't work for python2 with unicode input (because of `str.upper`).

Comment: `lambda x: x.upper()`, if you must deal with both `str` and `unicode`.

Answer (score 0):

Another method that uses [regex](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) to handle any non-alphanumeric characters.

```
import re

text = """The 1862 Derby was memorable due to the large field (34 horses), 
the winner being ridden by a 16-year-old stable boy and Caractacus' 
near disqualification for an underweight jockey and a false start."""

def selective_uppercase(word, index):
    if  index%2: 
        return str.upper(word)
    else: 
        return word

words, non_words =  re.split("\W+", text), re.split("\w+", text)
print "".join(selective_uppercase(words[i],i) + non_words[i+1] \
              for i in xrange(len(words)-1) )
```

Output:

```
The 1862 Derby WAS memorable DUE to THE large FIELD (34 HORSES), 
the WINNER being RIDDEN by A 16-YEAR-old STABLE boy AND Caractacus' 
NEAR disqualification FOR an UNDERWEIGHT jockey AND a FALSE start.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
user_word_2 = "I am passionate to code"


#block code to split the sentence
user_word_split_2 = user_word_2.split()   


#Empty list to store a to be split list of words, 

words_sep =""

#block code to make every alternate word

for i in range(0, len(user_word_split_2)): #loop to make every second letter upper

    if i % 2 == 0:
        words_sep = words_sep + " "+ user_word_split_2[i].lower() 

    else:
        words_sep = words_sep +" " + user_word_split_2[i].upper() 
    

#Block code to join the individual characters
final_string_2 = "".join(words_sep)

#Block code to product the final results
print(final_string_2)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```py
s = "Here is my dog"

words = s.split()
words[1::2] = map(str.upper, words[1::2])
s = " ".join(words)

print(s)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY384sVbBWUPFKLUhUyixVyKxVS8tOVuLjK84tSQDLFesUFOZklGpoQkWhDKyujWKB4bmKBRnFJkV5pQUFqkY4CkqQmF9hEBSW9rPzMPA2wjCYXV0FRZl6JRrEmxFqo7TBXAAA)