# Uppercase every other word in a string using split/join

Tags: python, join, split, uppercase, lowercase

I have a string:

```
string = "Hello World"
```

That needs changing to:

```
"hello WORLD"
```

Using only split and join in Python.

Any help?

```
string = "Hello World" 

split_str = string.split()
```

Can't then work out how to get first word to lowercase second word to uppercase and join

Comment: Using **only split and join** seems like a difficult task. You will probably need `upper` too.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question and there are surely plenty of online resources to help you solve this problem rather than getting a quick answer here.

Comment: what you need if i/p in `hello how are you`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to upper case every other word in string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452616/how-to-upper-case-every-other-word-in-string-in-python)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The code below works for any number of words:

```
string = "Hello World"
words   =  string.split() # works also for multiple spaces and tabs
result  =  ' '.join((w.upper() if i&1 else w.lower()) for i,w in enumerate(words))
print(result)
# "hello WORLD"
```

Comment: What if OP has more than 2 words?

Comment: I edited the code to work with n-words.

Comment: I changed the code to `filter(None,string.split(' '))` to make it more general. Now it works for strings like `hello               World`.

Comment: This doesn't work very well if/when *string* contains 2 or more consecutive spaces or when any delimiter is, for example, a tab. Try it with *string = "Hello \tWorld"*

Comment: I just tried exacly that string and it worked. The code works for any number fo spaces and with tab delimiters.

Comment: @C-3PO It does work now because you changed the way you're calling *split()*. Well done

Answer (score 2):

OP's objective **cannot** be achieved just with *split()* and *join()*. Neither of those functions can be used to convert to upper- or lower-case.

The *cycle* class from the *itertools* module is ideal for this:

```
from itertools import cycle

words = 'hello world'

CYCLE = cycle((str.lower, str.upper))

print(*(next(CYCLE)(word) for word in words.split()))
```

**Output:**

```
hello WORLD
```

Comment: Nice solution! Do you know why if in the form `map(next(CYCLE), words.split())` doesn't work? Somehow the second function is never call, it seems a kind of  _generator_ side-effect

Comment: @cards If you use the map construct, all words will be applied to str.lower because map doesn't iterate over its first parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
string = str(input("Enter any sentence here: "))      #prompt user for input

split_string = string.split()                         #to store the split string -creates a list

final_string = ""                                     #to compile the resulting string

for i in range(len(split_string)):                      #for loop for repeat operation

    if i % 2 == 0:
        final_string += split_string[i].upper() + " "   #if item index divides by 2 then convert to uppercase

    else:
        final_string += split_string[i].lower() + " "   #otherwise convert to lowercase

print(final_string)
```

Answer (score -1):

**for many words**:

make a list of words using `split`

connect everything with `" "` using `join`

inside we run through the list using `i` up to the length of this list

if this is an odd number, then `upper` otherwise `lower` (because the list is numbered from 0, and we need every second one)

```
string = "Hello World! It is Sparta!"
split_str  = string.split()
print(" ".join(split_str[i].upper() if i&1 else split_str[i].lower() for i in range(len(split_str))))

# hello WORLD! it IS sparta!
```

**for two words** (easy solution):

```
string = "Hello World"
split_str  = string.split()
print(' '.join([split_str[0].lower(),split_str[1].upper()]))

# hello WORLD
```

Comment: This only works for two words.

Comment: @C-3PO the condition is, no!?

Comment: Condition? The title asks in a generic manner: `Uppercase every other word in a string using split/join`

Comment: @C-3PO My bad. You were right. I'm still watching you create a monster in comment from a simple task, but it turns out that there is something in the title that is not in the body of the task. Fixed by using a slightly different loop from you - using the length of the list.