# Making each alternative word lower and upper case

Tags: python, uppercase

> Ask for a string from the user and make each alternative word lower and upper case (e.g. the string “I am learning to code” would
> become “i AM learning TO code”). Using the split and join functions will help you here.

I did a similar thing for characters in the string, but as I found out it doesn't work with full words.

```
new_string = input("Please enter a string: ")
char_storage = "" #blank string to store all the string's characters
char = 1

for i in new_string: 
    if char % 2 == 0:
        char_storage += i.lower()
    else:   
        char_storage += i.upper()
    char += 1

print(char_storage)
```

I am still quite confused about how python connects char with new_string value, if anyone has a good website where it is explained I would be very grateful.

Comment: Does it make more sense if you replace all occurrences of `i` with `letter`?

Comment: Iterating over the string character by character doesn't help. Iterate over `new_string.split()` word by word instead.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74420927/uppercase-every-other-word-in-a-string-using-split-join/74421273#74421273)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
new_string = input("Please enter a string: ")
char_storage = "" #blank string to store all the string's characters
char = 1

for i in new_string.split(): 
    if char != 1:
        char_storage += " "
    if char % 2 == 0:
        char_storage += i.lower()
    else:   
        char_storage += i.upper()
    char += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop over words, not characters of a string, so split your input into words, ex. on whitespace

```
new_string = input("Please enter a string: ").split()
```

The Python official documentation tells you that strings are iterable objects. Iterating them gives you characters.

---

I'd recommend separating code into functions and using str.join

```
def change_case(x, upper):
    return x.upper() if upper else x.lower()
char_storage = ' '.join(change_case(x, i%2!=0) for i, x in enumerate(new_string))
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest answer I can come up with would be:

```
new_string = input("Please enter a string: ").split()
char_storage = " ".join([x.upper() if i % 2 else x.lower() for i, x in enumerate(new_string)])
print(char_storage)
```

With `" ".join()` you can concatenate every word in a list by a space. The argument creates a list of words in the input phrase and switches characters to upper if the modulo is not 0.